# object expressions don't work in $filter of $projection stage

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
   $project: {
                  tar: {
                    $filter: {
                      input: "$tar",
                      cond: {
                        "$$tar.name": "ally",
                      },
                      as: "tar",
                    },
                  },
                },
```

```
MongoServerError: Invalid $project :: caused by :: Unrecognized expression '$$tar.name'
```

Is this expected? How do I get it to work with object expressions?

Comment: Does `cond: {"$eq": ["$$tar.name", "ally"]}` help?

Comment: that works yes. But my conditions are generated by a function to be object expressions.

Comment: Would you show this function, its input(s), and output(s)?

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has 2 distinct syntax types:
[Query](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/document/#query-filter-documents) syntax, and [aggregation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/meta/aggregation-quick-reference/#expressions) syntax.

As noted in the documentation for [$filter](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#-filter--aggregation-) the expression for `$cond` expects an aggregation expression.

What you called "object expressions" looks quite a bit like query syntax, which is not supported in an aggregation expression.